# I am not able to get data from model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Model

//returns an array having different arrays inside it with keys id ,name and thumbnail taken from the database

```
function m_get_thumbnails($category){
    $this->db->select('id,name,thumbnail');
    $this->db->where('category',$category);
    $query=$this->db->get('food');
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $count =0;
        $arr = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {

            $arr[$count++] = array(
                'id'=>$row->id,
                'name'=>$row->name,
                'thumbnail'=>$row->thumbnail
                );
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

function in controller

After that i place the result in an array and pass the array to my view.

```
function index_food()
{ 
    $data['cafe'] =  $this->mlocus->m_get_thumbnails('cafe');
    $this->load->view('food.php',$data);
}
```

View

```
<script>alert(<?php $cafe[1]; ?>);</script>
//this alert is coming blank.......
```

Comment: Try `$this->db->select('id,name,thumbnail,category');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
function index_food()
{ 
   $data['cafe'] =  $this->mlocus->m_get_thumbnails('cafe');
   $this->load->view('food',$data);
}
```

In Model

```
function m_get_thumbnails($category)
{
    $this->db->select('id,name,thumbnail');
    $this->db->where('category',$category);
    $query=$this->db->get('food');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In your View

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Thumbnail</td>
</tr>
<?php 
if(!empty($cafe)) {
foreach($cafe as $c){
?>
<tr>
  <td> <?php echo $c['id']?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $c['name']?> </td>
  <td><img src="<?php echo $c['thumbnail']?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php } } else { ?>
<tr><td colspan="3">No record found.</td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your function in Model

```
function m_get_thumbnails($category)
{
    $this->db->select('id,name,thumbnail');
    $this->db->where('category',$category);
    $query=$this->db->get('food')->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

In your View

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Thumbnail</td>
</tr>
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($cafe);$i++){?>
<tr>
  <td> <?php echo $cafe[$i]['id']?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $cafe[$i]['name']?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $cafe[$i]['thumbnail']?> </td> <!-- Use <img> if you have a url -->
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```